# Need to get 'Yes if source list include both type of values 'NA' and other values, return 'No' if source list include just 'NA'

Tags: sql, database, oracle

One of request for my code is to set value for Policy Exception 'Yes', 'No' and 'Null' for next 4 scenarios:

a. Source table can have next CODE:
'AAR',
'DSC',
'FCCR',
'**NA**' -> In this case I need to set value 'YES';

c. Source list can have values **without** '**NA**' :
'AAR',
'DSC',
'FCCR'-> In this case I need to set also value 'YES'

b. Source table can have just value 'NA' -> In this case I need to set value 'NO'

c. Source table can be empty -> In this case I need to set value 'NULL'

Could you please help me to create the code. Its challenging for me step a and b.
I used COUNT(DISTINCT CODE) but something went wrong.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear to me which is the _source table_ and which is the _source list_. Also, your four scenarios are numbered **a.**, **c.**, **b.** and **c.**. Shouldn't that be `a.`, `b.`, `c.` and `d.` ? And don't post images of data. Post it as text. Refer to [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Post the full query that you have tried so far?

Comment: I see these scenarios: NA and others => YES, FCCR and optionally others => YES, NA and no others => NO, no rows => NULL. What I am missing is the scenario only others (i.e. only entries that are neither NA nor FCCR), e.g. only AAR + DSC. What to do in this case? Or is this not possible? And the examples you are showing always have entries four in the table which can be null. Is this how it really is? I'd rather expect an app_id in the app table that has no row in your table instead of having four rows where the policy exception is always null.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood it - conditional aggregation.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (app_id, policyexceptions) as
  2    (select 57, 'AAR'  from dual union all
  3     select 57, 'DSC'  from dual union all
  4     select 57, 'FCCR' from dual union all
  5     select 57, 'NA'   from dual union all
  6     --
  7     select 58, 'AAR'  from dual union all
  8     select 58, 'DSC'  from dual union all
  9     select 58, 'FCCR' from dual union all
 10     select 58, 'AMO'  from dual union all
 11     --
 12     select 59, 'NA'   from dual union all
 13     select 59, 'NA'   from dual union all
 14     select 59, null   from dual union all
 15     select 59, null   from dual union all
 16     --
 17     select 50, null   from dual union all
 18     select 50, null   from dual union all
 19     select 50, null   from dual union all
 20     select 50, null   from dual
 21    ),
```

Query begins here; lines #37-40 have (as a comment) ordinal number of conditions you specified. I didn't use "a, b, c" because you have two "c" options, so ... I doubt it is correct, one of them should be "d"

```
 22  temp as
 23    (select app_id,
 24       sum(case when policyexceptions = 'NA'  then 1
 25                when policyexceptions is null then null
 26                else 0 end) sum_na,
 27       sum(case when policyexceptions = 'NA'  then 0
 28                when policyexceptions is null then null
 29                else 1 end) sum_not_na,
 30       sum(case when policyexceptions is null then 1 else 0 end) sum_null,
 31       count(*) cnt
 32     from test
 33     group by app_id
 34    )
 35  select app_id,
 36    --
 37    case when sum_null = cnt then 'Null'                -- 4)
 38         when sum_na > 0 and sum_not_na > 0 then 'Yes'  -- 1)
 39         when sum_na = 0 and sum_not_na > 0 then 'Yes'  -- 2)
 40         when sum_na + sum_null = cnt       then 'No'   -- 3)
 41    end as status
 42  from temp
 43  order by app_id;

    APP_ID STATUS
---------- ----------
        50 Null
        57 Yes
        58 Yes
        59 No

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a common table expression that summarises how many of each type of policy exceptions there are for each app_id, then use a case to chose the final result:

```sql
with summary as (
  select
    app_id,
    sum(case when policyexceptions = 'NA' then 1 else 0 end) as na_cnt,
    sum(case when policyexceptions != 'NA' then 1 else 0 end) as other_cnt
  from mytable
  group by app_id
)
select
  app_id,
  case
    when other_cnt > 0 then 'YES'
    when other_cnt = 0 and na_cnt > 0 then 'NO'
    else null
  end as policyexception
from summary
```

See [live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=627653886bde5915f8d892c6d96b476a).

Comment: Thank you! Never used this function sum(case when...). It works perfect for my case.